Can ACME be used as a replacement for SCEP in terms of getting user/device certificates?
I want to understand if I can use ACME to get identity(user/device) certificates from CA server for my iOS devices. I am currently using SCEP to get the certificates from CA server.
I read a few links on the internet and understand that ACME is mainly a solution for SSL certificates.
I wanted to know if I can use ACME to get identity certificates? If it can be used as a replacement for SCEP?
If anyone could provide me with any useful/helpful links to start with I would be grateful

Yes, ACME is a modern replacement for SCEP. If your clients and CA support ACME, then you can switch from SCEP to ACME. Though details would vary significantly depending on your environment. ACME isn't suitable only for SSL, it is just where it was first widely adopted.
